Why is my code using relative paths not working on Ubuntu?
I am trying to read and write files using Python in Visual Studio Code and it is not working properly when I'm on Ubuntu. The path of the script appears to be incorrect to use relative paths.
For example this simple write to a file code:
with open('../out/file_name.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.truncate()

I must specify the full path for the file using 'os' library to make it work:
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
out_dir = os.path.join(script_directory, '../out')
write_file_path = os.path.join(
    out_dir, 'file_name.txt')
with open(write_file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.truncate()

I do not have this problem when using Windows.
This problem also affects importing classes and methods from other files found in the same work directory.
My project structure is:

use-case1

agent

data

txt


out
src

main.py




sim



PWD command in the terminal returns /home/user/Documents/Project/Project-Use-Cases/use-case1.

is this problem reproducible when executing the code from console? If not then it's not an Ubuntu but a VSC problem.

Add the command you use to execute the script, is it from terminal? From VSCode? Double clicked from File Exporer? Also add pwd() and ls -lah

This with open('../out/file_name.txt', 'w') will try to open ../out/file_name.txt on the working directory, so where you execute the command

This on the other hand os.path.dirname(__file__), grabs the path of the python file you're executing, which is why it could be wotking in this case.

Can you provide us with the project structure?

I added project structure and PWD.

You are apparently using two different working directories on the two systems. In one (that works) you current folder is <path>/use-case1/agent/src on the other (not working) it is something else.
